# drop down nspathcontrol

Tags: cocoa, nspathcontrol

Is there a way to get the default NSPathControl to have drop down like in xcode 4? by default i mean without subclassing

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized the popup menu is just the menu outlet. All I have to do is create a menu and make a single click display the menu.